# Component update issue

Tags: angular, typescript

So I'm having this issue. I have a component that use the

`changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

the component have this logic :

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.serivce.something
  .subscribe( evt => {
    // Logic that update values of the array (the logic works)
  });
}
```

the html is something like that :

```
...
...
<div *ngFor="let item of myArray">
  <span *ngIf="item.showEye">TRUE</span>
  <span *ngIf="!item.showEye"> FALSE</span>
</div>
...
...
```

the problem is that, using this strategy, it won't render the component even if I have changed something. This is what the array looks like before doing the edits :

[image]

**note that showEye is setted to true**

Here's after the edit :

[image]

As you can see `showEye` is now false. But guess what? Nothing changed in the html.

So my question is, since I can't remove that strategy, how to "tell" the component to re-render it self?

Comment: Can you show us your full component code?

Comment: A quick workaround is to force change detection using `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` after your values have been updated: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectChanges

Comment: what you try jacopo and are you doing this angularjs or angular

Comment: There's nothing relevant, just functions that are never called for now @Exterminator

Comment: you can use `ngOnChanges()` to call the `ngOnInit()` again

Comment: @David was right, simply as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update your html try this:

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {...}

ngOnInit(){
    this.serivce.something
        .subscribe( evt => {
            // Logic that update values of the array (the logic works)
            this.cd.detectChanges(); // Triggers a change detection run
    });
}
```

Because you have set the changeDetection to ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush you have disabled the automatic change detection, so you need to trigger it by yourself.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. Also a big thanks to @David

Answer (score 0):

Angular has two types of **ChangeDetectionStrategy** the **Default** and the **OnPush**. The main difference is that OnPush only works with **immutable** objects and arrays. That is only if it is passed another reference the change detection of OnPush will be trigered. So it works very well with observables since you can handle any change of a variable as something like 'next; in a subject in which each change returns a new object and the previous object is discarded.

Example:

```
@Component({
  ....
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MyOnPushComponent {
 person:Person = {
    name: 'Tom',
    age: 15
}

changeName(){
   this.person.name='Ralf'; // Doesnt triger the change detection of OnPush because it is the same reference (would be on default)
}



  changePerson(){
       this.person={
        name: 'Ted',
        age: 20
    }; // OnPush change detection is triggered because it refers to a new object
  }

}
```

Comment: The logic is that: The main component update a BehaviorSubject in a service, the ComposerComponent (that one that use the strategy) subscribe to that BehaviorSubject in the onInit and everytime the Dashboard emit something, it catches the event, executing the logic. Was just the .html not re-rendering. ChangeDetectorRef  solved my problem